# Is it possible to load a rpt to a subreport dynamically?

Tags: crystal-reports

I would like to create a kind of master report, with 2 sections. The first will contains a subreport that will always be the same. The other section will contain a subreport that would be loaded with differents .rpt files, depending on some business rules.

I tried to use something like:

```
report.Subreport["subReportName"].Load("path to desired .rpt")
```

But Crystal return an error saying it is an invalid operation. There is another way to do that?!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Tiago! If you get a response that answers your question, please green-check it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have the main report load all the subreports all the time, but only display the one you want conditionally.

Hide the subreports you don't want conditionally, in other words.

Comment: Thank you! I was going to do that, but I thought there would be a more elegant solution! :) I read somewhere it is not possible to load a subreport, and I would like to be sure about it...